# List the 5 most recent child pages

Tags: wp-query, query, child-pages, children

I created a hierarchical custom post type for a gallery. The parent pages are the galleries and the child pages are the albums. I want to display the most recent albums on my sidebar (so basically the most recent child pages).

```
'post_parent' => 0
```

I only find this in the codex, but this is the opposite i want, this will only list the parent pages. Here is my code so far:

```
$albums = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'posts_per_page' => 6
));
```

Comment: Can you please include in your question the relevant `register_post_type()` code? Your terminology is a bit confusing. A `page` is a specific post-type, and I'm unsure if you simply mean that you've created a hierarchical `gallery` post-type, and refer to different *content* on parent vs. child `gallery` posts, or if you have a `gallery` post-type and an `album` post-type.

Comment: Sorry, its a bit confusing. Your first assume was right, i created a hierarchical post type called gallery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know (or know how to get) the `$id` (as an *integer*) of the parent post, use [the **`post_parent`** parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters):

```
$albums = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_parent' => $id
));
```

### Edit

Based on this comment:

> I don't know the parent post. I want to list the most recent child pages from ANY parent page.

While it is easy to query only *parent* pages (by passing `'post_parent' => 0`), it is not quite so simple to query only *child* pages.

One method would be to query all `gallery` posts, loop through them, and add any that have a `post_parent` into another variable; then output *that* variable.

```
// Query all gallery posts
$all_albums = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
) );

// Array to hold latest albums
$latest_child_albums = array();
// Latest album counter
$latest_albums_count = 0;
// If we already have 5, no need to keep looping
while ( 5 < $latest_albums_count ) {
    // Loop through each gallery post
    foreach ( $all_albums as $album ) {
        // If the current post has a parent
        if ( $album->post_parent != 0 ) {
            // Add it to the latest albums array
            $latest_child_albums[] = $album;
            // Increment the counter
            $latest_albums_count++;
        }
    }
}

// Loop through the array of latest albums
if ( $latest_child_albums->have_posts() ) : while ( $latest_child_albums->have_posts() ) : $latest_child_albums->the_post();
    // Loop content here
endwhile; endif;
// Be kind; rewind.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I don't know the parent post. I want to list the most recent child pages from ANY parent page.

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: The edited version is a solution, but i think its a little overkill? Especially if i have hundreds of albums. Its working, so thanks.